# BDD test framework for Clojure

Tags: clojure, bdd

Googling reveals only answers to this question from the last few years and some of the projects I've looked at in github haven't had commits for a long time. Is anyone working on anything at the moment? I'm interested in contributing. Also does anything test in parallel? I'm new to Clojure but one thing it seems to be missing is a test framework as good as ScalaTest.

Answer (score 3):

I think [speclj](http://speclj.com/) is still active.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/zenmodeler/spexec is something relatively recent and devoted to BDD.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm also has clojure support and there's a runnable example in the `clojure` directory; an extended example of its use is here: https://github.com/gphilipp/bdd-guide-clojure

Answer (score 1):

[Eggplant](https://github.com/perkss/eggplant) is a exciting new BDD open source library used for Clojure. You can also read about it [here](https://perkss.github.io/#/clojure).

For example:

```
(defspec multiplying-two-numbers
  (specification
   {:given "a input of :a and :b"
    :when  "we #* :c"
    :then  "we expect :result"
    :data {:a 3 :b 4 :result 12}}))

(defspec change-a-string-to-uppercase
 (specification
  {:given "a input of :a"
   :when  "we #clojure.string/upper-case"
   :then  "we expect :result"
   :data {:a "hello" :result "HELLO"}}))

(defspec finding-the-max-of-two-numbers
 (specification
  {:expect "the #max of :a and :b"
   :where  {:a 2 :b 3 :expected 3}}))
```

***"Simplicity is key"***

Five keywords:

- given
- when
- then
- expect
- where

https://github.com/perkss/eggplant

Focusing on data driven development and testing it via spec by example using a human readable form which maintains specification documentation as the tests grow.

The standard `clojure.test` will run these so compatible with any IDE and build tool.

Developers can write a quick easy to follow BDD test in a very short time.